# How to sort a stdclassobject array in php?

Tags: php

I have this stdclass object array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [message] => c

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [message] => b

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [message] => a
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (

            [id] => 4
            [message] => d
        )

)
```

but I need to sort this with respect to their id values ....

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried [basic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) from the documentation? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

PHP provides the `usort` function for this: [usort documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$sortedArray = usort($array, function($a, $b) {
        return $a->id - $b->id;
    });
```